# how to see difference between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: 1 temp and the other one is my main table.

Each day I would update my temp table and I want to update my main table based on the changes I made from the temp table.

Example: The first temp table contains an id and name. Then I insert the value from temp into the main table. But when I made changes from my temp like insert another id and name, I want my main table to compare and only insert the unique id from the temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, it seems like you have a table object named as temp table. If this is the case then you may use `after insert trigger` on temp table to insert new inserted value in your main table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterINSERTTrigger on [Temptable]
FOR INSERT 
AS DECLARE @id INT,
       @col1 VARCHAR(50),
       .
       .

SELECT @id = ins.id FROM INSERTED ins;
SELECT @col1 = ins.col1 FROM INSERTED ins;
.
.


INSERT INTO [MainTable]( 
       [id]
      ,[col1]
       .
       .)
VALUES (@id,
    @col1,
    .
    .
    .
    );
PRINT 'We Successfully Fired the AFTER INSERT Triggers in SQL Server.'
GO
```

Similarly you can update your table on update of record in temptable using `update trigger`. You may find this link on more info on trigger. [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**OR**

If you are creating temp table object to get the new inserted record then use simple `not in` or `not exists` clause to get the newly inserted record.

Using `NOT IN`

```
insert into maintable ( id, col1, ...)
select Id , col1, .... from temptable 
where id not in (select id from maintable)
```

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
insert into maintable ( id, col1, ... )
select id, col1, ... from temptable as temp 
where not exists (select id from maintable as main where main.id=temp.id)
```

Comment: How do you know Michael is using SQL Server?

Comment: i use not exists as it seems easier, but i'll try the after insert trigger for practice later, thanks

Comment: i did but it says that i have less than 15 reputation so it  didn't change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows

```
INSERT into main_table(
    id, name,
    ...
)
SELECT
    id,name,
    ...
FROM temp_table t
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM main_table m
        WHERE m.id = t.id
    )
```

Cheers!!